# AMPscript Code Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

Hi I have 2 Data extension

1. Unique MO
2. Credit Limit 80 out 100 used CCA 1001

I'm querying Unique MO and for each unique Mo i have multiple dealers data in 2nd DE which is Credit Limit 80 out 100 used CCA 1001 but I'm only getting last queried Data for dealers that to same data when sending the email to each unique MO. Pasting the AMPscript code here.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
%%[
var @active, @uniquerow, @uniquerowCount, @region, @i, @uniquerows
set @active = "True"
set @uniquerows = LookupRows("Unique MO", "isActive", @active)
set @uniquerowCount = rowcount(@uniquerows)

if @uniquerowCount > 0 then
]%%
<table border="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <th>MO Name</th>
    <th>Dealer Name</th>
    <th>Dealer Code</th>
    <th>Net Outstanding(₹)</th>
    <th>Total Credit Limit(₹)</th>
    <th>Credit Limit Utilization(%)</th>
  </tr>


%%[
var @uniqueMoName, @rows, @row, @rowCount, @j
var @DealerName, @DelaerCode, @NetOutstanding, @TotalCreditLimit, @CreditLimitUtilization

 for @i = 1 to @uniquerowCount do
  set @uniquerow = row(@uniquerows, @i)
  set @uniqueMoName = field(@uniquerow, "MO Name")
  
  set @rows = LookupRows("Credit Limit 80 out 100 used CCA 1001", "MO Name", @uniqueMoName)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
  
  
    for @j = 1 to @rowCount do
      set @row = row(@rows, @j)
      set @DealerName = field(@row, "Dealer_Name__c")
      set @DelaerCode = field(@row, "Dealer_Code__c")
      set @NetOutstanding = field(@row, "Net_Outstanding__c")
      set @TotalCreditLimit = field(@row, "Total_Credit_Limit__c")
      set @CreditLimitUtilization = field(@row, "Credit Limit Utilization")
]%%

  <tr>
    <td>%%=v(@uniqueMoName)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=v(@DealerName)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=v(@DelaerCode)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=v(@NetOutstanding)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=v(@TotalCreditLimit)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=v(@CreditLimitUtilization)=%%</td>
  </tr>
  
%%[
  next @j
 next @i
endif
]%%
</table>
</div>
```